# CCJavascript Return True Page Refresh Error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, refresh

I am writing a form validation code in PHP. Below is the code.

the element with id #questionSubmit is a form with 6 text fields (code, question, answer, option1, option2, option3, option4, option5) and a submit button.

```
<form id="createQuestionForm" action="" method="POST">
    Question Code: <input id="code" class="createQuestionTextBox1" type="text" name="questionCode">
    Question Name: <input id="question" class="createQuestionTextBox1" type="text" name="questionName">
    Correct Answer: <input id="answer" class="createQuestionTextBox1" type="text" name="correctAnswer">
    Option 1: <input id="option1" class="createQuestionTextBox2" type="text" name="option_1">
    Option 2: <input id="option2" class="createQuestionTextBox2" type="text" name="option_2">
    Option 3 <input id="option3" class="createQuestionTextBox2" type="text" name="option_3">
    Option 4 <input id="option4" class="createQuestionTextBox2" type="text" name="option_4">
    Option 5 <input id="option5" class="createQuestionTextBox2" type="text" name="option_5">
    <input type="Submit" id="questionSubmit" value="Create Question"></input> 
</form>

function SubmitFormCreationData() {
    $("#questionSubmit").click(function() {
        if (CheckCodeField($("#code").val()) == false) {
            return false;
        } else if (CheckAnswerNameFields($("#question").val()) == false) {
            return false;
        } else if (CheckCorrectAnswerField($("#answer").val()) == false) {
            return false;
        } else if (CheckAnswerNameFields($("#option1").val()) == false) {
            return false;
        } else if (CheckAnswerNameFields($("#option2").val()) == false) {
            return false;
        } else if (CheckAnswerNameFields($("#option3").val()) == false) {
            return false;
        } else if (CheckAnswerNameFields($("#option4").val()) == false) {
            return false;
        } else if (CheckAnswerNameFields($("#option5").val()) == false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $.post("InsertNewQuestion.php", $('#createQuestionForm').serialize());
            alert('Quiz Created');
            window.setTimeout(delay,2000);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}

function CheckAnswerNameFields(value) {
    var isValid = true;

    if (value == "") 
        isValid = false;
    if (value == null)
        isValid = false;
    for(LCV = 0;LCV <= (count(value)-1); LCV++) {
        if(value[LCV] == "'")
            isValid = false;
        if(value[LCV] == '"')
            isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}

function CheckCodeField(value) {
    var isValid = true;

    if(isInteger(value) == false)
        isValid = false;
    if(value < 100000)
        isValid = false;
    if(value > 999999)
        isValid = false;

    return isValid;
}  

function CheckCorrectAnswerField(value) {
    var isValid = true;

    if(isInteger(value) == false)
        isValid = false;
    if(value < 1)
        isValid = false;
    if(value > 5)
        isValid = false;

    return isValid;
}

function isInteger(possibleInteger) {
    return /^[\d]+$/.text(possibleInteger);
}
```

Now if the first field is entered correctly then the output is as wanted, false is returned. However if the first field is entered correctly and the rest are blank then the page refreshes, however it should be returning false because I check if the question and option fields are blank. Why is this happening?

Comment: Client is bypassable, you must add the control on the page which called with ajax (on server-side)

Comment: why do you have three CheckCodeField functions?? Anyway that might not be the reason for the issue. And could you please post the form fields also?

Comment: Do u mean the HTML for the form?

Comment: yep.. it would help to find the problem.. :)

Comment: @Sam I don't quite understand, could you please elaborate? Do you mean I should paste the php code that handles the data from the form?

Comment: Yeah there should have only been one CheckCodeFieldFunction.

Comment: for start,you have few bugs : for(LCV = 0;LCV <= (count(value-1); LCV++) { //one ) not closed

Comment: other bug in the end isInteger should have function before name.

Comment: @Bojan Kovacevic Both those errors exist in the code I copied here they did not exist in the original code.

Comment: The machine I am coding on is different than this machine. The coding machine is standalone and no connections are allowed to it (no internet, no  USB). So I have to rewrite all of the code manually in stack overflow and thats why there are errors.

Comment: are you using any javascript debugger like firebug or chrome developer tool? do you have any javascript error?

Comment: The page refreshes so I am unable to see the error in the Chrome debugger. Nothing appears in the chrome browser so I assume that there is no error, unless the page refresh is biasing the debugger.

Comment: also javascript use length to calculate value length, not count(). unless you made your own implementation.

Comment: for debugging remove anything but alert in else section

Comment: I commented out the post, however the alert("Quiz Created") still does not appear. So it does not go in the last else.

Comment: I also put an alert in every if statement. Only the alert in the first statement is called, then the page refreshes.

Comment: add this to start of your javascript code to catch possible error: window.onerror = function (err, file, line) {
alert('The following error occured: ' + err + '\n' +
'In file: ' + file + '\n' +
'At line: ' + line);
return true;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $("#questionSubmit").click(function() {
        $.post("InsertNewQuestion.php", $('#createQuestionForm').serialize(), function(data){
        if(data=='SUCCESS'){
               alert('Quiz Created');
               window.setTimeout(delay,2000);
               return true;
               }
            else{
                var alertx='';
                for(i=0;i<data.split('-').length-1;i++) alertx += data.split('-')[i].toString()+"\n";
                alert(alertx);
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

insertnewquestion.php

```
extract($_POST);

 $errors = '';

if(!in_array($questionCode,range(100000,999999))) $errors .= 'Invalid code-';
if(!in_array($correctAnswer,range(1,5))) $errors .= "Invalid answer-";

 for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++){ 
   $var = $i==6 ? $questionName : ${'option_'.$i};
   if(empty($var) || strstr($var,'"') || strstr($var,"'")) $errors.= "Invalid ".($i==6?"question name":"option $i")."-"; 
    }

     echo $errors=='' ? 'SUCCESS':$errors;
```

Try and write if work correctly

Comment: Actually I need the form validation to work in the javascript because I am displaying the invalid boxes through jQuery in Javascript

Comment: I have a span beside each textbox which I populate with the text "Invalid!" which dissapears after 2 seconds

Comment: I havent written it in the code above as I thought it was unnecessary for debugging.

Comment: The client is dangerous for form controls, an expert user can send the vars to the php page without doing the client controls(js)

Comment: Sam is right, you can have validation in JavaScript, but still need some checking on server side.

Comment: true, ok I will implement this in server side in that case.